# Setting up a Client-Server LAN with restricted access

Tags: networking, client-server

I'm setting up a new LAN in a call center where there are 3 levels of employees:

```
- 1/ Me (the admin)

--- 2/ supervisor 1
------ 3/ teleoperator
------ 3/ teleoperator
------ 3/ teleoperator

--- 2/ supervisor 2
------ 3/ teleoperator
------ 3/ teleoperator
------ 3/ teleoperator
```

Now I want to setup a server for sharing files that:

- I have full access to EVERYTHING
- Supervisor 1 has full access ONLY to "FOLDER1" and subdirectories
- Supervisor 2 has full access ONLY to "FOLDER2" and subdirectories
- Teleoperators have access each ONLY to his "FOLDERx/TELEOPERATORx" and subdirectories

Any suggestions are welcome. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things (that I'm aware of):

1. Set up Folder access restriction or
2. Do multiple shares.

If you use Folder access Restriction:

**Pros:** Everyone access the same share (ie. \server\share) and can see all the folders, but they can only access the correct folder that they have access to.
**Cons:** May be a bit complicated at the initial set up, but may worth your time if you plan to expand the solution for more groups / shares.

So you (admin) will have full access over \server\share and all subfolders.
supervisor1 will have full access over \server\share\FOLDER1
teleoperator1 will have directory view access on FOLDER1, but can only access \server\share\FOLDER1\teleoperator1 folder. If Teleoperator1 tried to access other folder, it will not work.

If you use multiple shares:

**Pros:** Easy to set up
**Cons:** Can get very messy if you extend it to support even more groups - Only suitable for simple group sharing. Also this will make the visibility messy (ie. \server\share for you, \server\folder1 for supervisor1, \server\teleoperator1 for teleoperator1 etc)

Basically simply share each folder to the correct user, and it will just work. Messy.

Hope this helps.
PS: This is for Windows based solution, may be usable on Linux or Mac, but I'm not too familiar with the detail to be able to say for sure.